# Cannot import statsmodels.api due to scipy import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

For `import statsmodels.api`
I get

```
 File "C:\Users\Saul Ramirez\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import calc_lwork

ImportError: cannot import name 'calc_lwork'
```

When I check the directory above, the module calc_lwork is not in scipy.linalg.
When I check the scipy master branch on github, calc_lwork is not in scipy.linalg.
Did I install/build something incorrectly?

I am using the latest statsmodels and scipy, Spyder (Python 3.4)

Answer (score 1):

This is a current bug. Please see [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2184) for more details. You can downgrade scipy to 0.14 or update statmodels to master.

Comment: update: scipy 0.15.1 has been released which fixes the backwards compatibility problem, and released versions of statsmodels should work using scipy 0.15.1.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem occured when I was using Python 2(2.7.12).
It worked fine with python3 (3.6.3)